# await in winform not work

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

When I try to debug this application, the following code would be block

```
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
```

In WinForm application.

And in console app, it works good. Is there anyone know what caused this and how to solve it?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Run().Wait();
    }

    public async Task Run()
    {
        await Run2();
    }

    public static async Task<bool> Run2()
    {
        var task = Task.FromResult(true);
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
        return await task;
    }
}
```

Comment: "The following code". I assume you mean "I expect the next line to be executed to be...". After what? What do you see when debugging? I expect that after `await Run2()` you return to your form constructor, because `await` immediately returns.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with `Run().Wait();`?  Why do people spawn threads/tasks only to immediately block?

Comment: @oerkelens It means, when you debug, it stopped right there in that line.

Comment: @MickyD This is for testing. In real environment, for example, we need to init database or anything asynchronously.

Comment: Search term "c# async deadlock"

Comment: `we need to init database or anything asynchronously` - see my blog on [asynchronous constructors](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reference: [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

> And in console app, it works good. Is there anyone know what caused this

Note: Don’t mix blocking and async code

Exception: Console main method

> “Async all the way” means that you shouldn’t mix synchronous and
>   asynchronous code without carefully considering the consequences. In
>   particular, it’s usually a bad idea to block on async code by calling
>   Task.Wait or Task.Result.

---

> and how to solve it?

Use async event handler.

```
public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Load += Loaded;
}

public async void Loaded(object sender, EventArgs args) {

    await Run();//Non blocking thread
}

public async Task Run() {
    await Run2();
}

public static async Task<bool> Run2() {
    var task = Task.FromResult(true);
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
    return await task;
}
```